# What is the difference between the [http-404] and the [broken-link] tags on Meta?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

Here on Meta, there are two tags, [http-404](/questions/tagged/http-404) and [broken-link](/questions/tagged/broken-link) that both relate to the same thing: to report links that cause 404 errors on the site. However, the [http-404](/questions/tagged/http-404) tag is also used to discuss the 404 page itself. What is the difference between the tags? Should we merge them, or change their purposes so that one is for reporting broken links and the other is for discussing the 404 page?

Comment: A meta-meta-stackoverflow question!

Comment: @Linuxios Hence tagged [meta-tag:meta]...

Comment: I almost want to start a proposal on Area51 for Meta Meta Stackoverflow :).

Comment: @Linuxios I have a feeling that this would be closed as duplicate of Meta anyway...

Comment: @Linuxios meta is meta enough

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're really not the same thing.

Personally, I've always thought the [http-404](/questions/tagged/http-404) tag looked kind of tacky. Only a programmer would even know what that means, and this is supposed to be the hub for all network issues. It really doesn't make sense to me for that tag to exist. I'd rather it be something like [error-page](/questions/tagged/error-page), but apparently that tag is "reserved" for the 500 Internal Server Error page. Since the 404 and 500 pages *are* different from one another, I'm not sure how viable merging them together would be.

That being said, it's also not the same as the [broken-link](/questions/tagged/broken-link) tag, which is for questions about broken links within posts and comments, and not about 404 error pages on the network. I've updated the tag wiki excerpt to the following:

> For discussing the effects of broken links within posts and comments across the network, what to do with them, and how we can prevent them from becoming broken.

Comment: So that's the tag's intent. But there are questions that are tagged with [meta-tag:broken-link] that relate to network 404 errors...

Comment: So retag them? A tag being misused is not a good reason to just merge them together.

Comment: Yeah, go ahead. It was unclear what the tag meant because it had no wiki summary, and there were lots of questions tagged with it that should have been tagged with [meta-tag:http-404], so that's why I asked this question. I edited it to clarify.

Comment: @animuson What about using [tag:page-not-found] for the 404 tag? It's the title of [the 404 page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/asdf).